# Adding IEEE Copyright to LaTex document

Tags: latex

I am trying to add a IEEE Copyright note to my Latex document.

I've used the following commands

```
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\IEEEpubid{\makebox[\columnwidth]{...abcdcopyright \hfill}    \hspace{\columnsep}\makebox[\columnwidth]{ }}

\maketitle
\IEEEpubidadjcol
```

I am using the

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
```

The output I am getting is

[image: this]

I want the copyright notice to be like

[image: this]

I really need some help with this! Thank you!